# Is it necessary to replace a furnace when replacing the air conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning

When replacing a central Air Conditioner is it also necessary to replace the furnace,which is part of a forced air system. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Bob, the coil unit (evaporator) in your air handling section is the only part that needs to be changed. With new units this may mean a new sheet metal frame to house the new evaporator coil but I find many furnaces out last at least 1-2 AC units.

Don't let them talk you into cleaning and reusing the coil or line set if it is a R12/R22 refrigerant type as it's almost impossible to get all the old oil out and then your new unit will have a much shorter life.